# How can we load paginated data in ajax calls of the event in FullCalendar 4.0?

Tags: fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar 4.0 to display rosters for all staff members on the calendar. However, when the rosters exceed 500, the FullCalendar renders the data very slowly. Is it possible to fetch the data in chunks during the events AJAX call?

I checked the documentation but didn't find any solution.